# How to overwrite @Produce JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs

My RESTFul Web service GET method returns Java object which gets converted to JSON by using @Produce anotation on the method.
I want to append JSON response to CallBack as CallBack(JSON Response). How this can be acheived?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

If you mean wrapping the body of the original response with "CallBack(...)" text, then you can do it with Jersey using the ContainerResponseFilter - see the javadoc to read more on container filters: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/package-summary.html

In this particular case you can define the filter as follows:

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class MyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static class Wrapper implements ContainerResponseWriter {
        private final ContainerResponseWriter crw;

        private long contentLength;

        private ContainerResponse response;

        private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

        Wrapper (ContainerResponseWriter crw) {
            this.crw = crw;
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream writeStatusAndHeaders(long contentLength, ContainerResponse response) throws IOException {
            this.contentLength = contentLength;
            this.response = response;
            return this.baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public void finish() throws IOException {
            byte[] entity = baos.toByteArray();

//            response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "desired_new_content_type");

            OutputStream out = crw.writeStatusAndHeaders(contentLength, response);
            ReaderWriter.writeToAsString("CallBack(", out, response.getMediaType());
            out.write(entity);
            ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(")", out, response.getMediaType());
            crw.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.isCompatible(response.getMediaType())) {
            response.setContainerResponseWriter(
                    new Wrapper(response.getContainerResponseWriter()));
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Btw, you may want to use a different media type to indicate you want the wrapping to occur and in the filter change it to application/json so that the subsequent processing happens correctly. In the response filter you can then change it back to whatever it was when wrapping the result (see the commented out line above).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean a JSONp? If you use cxf there is a filter for it.

Comment: Hi Peter, As I mentioned before I want to alter the JSON response generated by @Produce before it is sent back. How and where can I intervene to do this.

Comment: you can add a filter to your controller, that has access to both the request and response. If you want to do something standard, e.g.: JSONp then there is an off the shelf solution otherwise you can create one yourself

Comment: I'm using Jersey with Jettison. I'm not sure where and how can I use filters. Can you please give me an example. Code snippet will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it is a standard web technology. Create a class that extends javax.servlet.Filter and define it in your web.xml. A tutorial is here : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat.html